# Execute package task in errorhandling gives error

Tags: ssis, azure-data-factory, ssis-2017

In my OnError eventhandler I try to execute a (child) package but I get this error:

`Error: Error 0x80040154. Failed to create an instance of empty child package. The Distributed Component Object Model (DCOM) configuration or the installation of SQL Server Integration Services, may be corrupted on your machine.`

followed by `Class not registered`

This happens even if it is an empty package I call.
Is it not possible to execute an package in an EventHandler?
What else could lead to this error?

Packages are set as `ExecuteOutOfProcess`

Using Visual Studio 2019 with microsoft integration services installed.

Edit:
Setting ExecuteOutOfProcess to FALSE made the empty package run.
Another package with 3rdparty-components however failed.
But that is cleaclry caused by that 3party component. Investigating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling the Integration Sevrices Add-on solved the problem